# How can I see which is my boot partition?

Tags: command-line, server, partitioning

I want to see which partition (`/dev/sdaX`) is my boot partition. I'm using Ubuntu Server, so I need a command line solution

I tried this, but the output was ambiguous as two partitions were shown:

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep 'Linux' | cut -d' ' -f1 2>&1
```

How can I get the boot partition name?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Boot partition

In order to find the boot partition I would use the command `df /boot`for an installed Ubuntu system (standard Ubuntu, Ubuntu Server and the community flavours Kubuntu, Lubuntu ... Xubuntu),

```
$ df /boot
Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda8      103162996 30558020  67341528  32% /
```

or if you want a clean output with only the partition,

```
$ df /boot | grep -Eo '/dev/[^ ]+'
/dev/sda8
```

### Boot partition and EFI partition in UEFI mode

In order to find the boot partition and the EFI partition in an Ubuntu system booted in UEFI mode (both are use during boot),

```
$ test -d /sys/firmware/efi/ && echo efi || echo bios
efi

$ df /boot
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda2      303017780 3281532 284320780   2% /
```

You can use `fdisk` (as you have been trying)  or `parted` to find the EFI partition,

```
$ sudo fdisk -lu|grep -i efi
/dev/sda1      65535   1048559    983025   480M EFI System

$ sudo parted -ls|grep -i efi
 1      33.6MB  537MB  503MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
```

Parted does not provide the drive letter on the same line as the partition number, but you can use the full information and your eyes,

```
$ sudo parted -ls            
Model: WDC WD32 00BEKT-00PVMT0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 320GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                  Flags
 1      33.6MB  537MB  503MB   fat32           EFI System Partition  boot, esp
 2      537MB   316GB  315GB   ext4
 3      316GB   320GB  4161MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: @Zanna, I started to omit the $ character, when I noticed, that some users are confused by it, and complain that it does not work (some even supply the output `$: command not found`

Comment: [Command not found $](//askubuntu.com/q/898404) - I never include `$` when the line is only the command, only to distinguish it from the output. I've decided that's the least confusing way. I go around deleting dollar signs from posts that include them where there's no output. But if there is output, I use the `$` in case people think the output is a command! It's up to you how you want to do it

Comment: @Zanna, So you are still in favour of using the $ character to tell the command from it output. It is OK with me, I'll try to remember to do it this way.

Comment: @MidoBona, you are welcome :-)

Comment: @sudodus can u help me in this question https://askubuntu.com/questions/962554/squashfs-operation-not-supported

Answer (score 1):

I realised that I could `grep` for the `*` that flags the boot partition like this:

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep '*  ' | cut -d' ' -f1 2>&1
```

That solved my problem.

Comment: this won't work on an EFI system and might not be reliable since other lines in `fdisk` output can contain `*` with a trailing space

Answer (score 0):

Mido's answer is what I was looking for.

To overcome the reliability issue Zanna pointed out, I'd propose:

```
sudo fdisk -l | grep ' \*   ' | cut -d' ' -f1
```

Should get the only match this time.