# squashfs: Operation not supported

Tags: server, squashfs

I am using ubuntu server 14.04.1 and i want edit filesystem.squashfs after installed squashfs-tools and unsquashfs and edit filesystem and mksquashfs and build iso i get this error

```
base-installer: info: Using squashfs support for /cdrom/install/filesystem.squashfs
anna-install: Installing squashfs-modules
anna[21857]: DEBUG: resolver (kernel-image-4.2.0-16-generic-di): package doesn't exist (ignored)
anna[21857]: DEBUG: retrieving squashfs-modules-4.2.0-16-generic-di 4.2.0-16.19
kernel: [44.008353] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
main-menu[3537]: (process:21801): getfattr: .: Operation not supported
main-menu[3537]: (process:21801): getfattr: ./bin: Operation not supported
main-menu[3537]: (process:21801): getfattr: ./bin/bunzip2: Operation not supported
main-menu[3537]: (process:21801): getfattr: ./bin/bzcat: Operation not supported
main-menu[3537]: (process:21801): getfattr: ./bin/bzcmp: Operation not supported
```

i think this error becouse kernel version not equal squashfs-tools

is this right ?

and i want install right package squashfs-tools support kernel ubuntu-server 14.04.1

and sorry if my english is bad

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66773/discussion-on-question-by-mido-bona-squashfs-operation-not-supported).

Answer (score 1):

The "answer" to your question is: The message " getfattr: [file name]: Operation not supported" is because squashfs does not support ACL.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissionsACLs

and http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/getfattr.1.html

> getfattr - get extended attributes of filesystem objects
>
> For each file, getfattr displays the file name, and the set of
>   extended attribute names (and optionally values) which are associated 
>   with  that file.

So, because squashfs does not support ACL or "extended attributes" , you are getting the message " getfattr: [file name]: Operation not supported", the files in your squashfs do not have extended attributes, period. The never will no matter what version of squashfs you use.

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/squashfs.txt

> ### 1. FILESYSTEM FEATURES
>
> **ACL support:            no          no**

In order to not get that message, don't use ACL.

That message has nothing to do with kernel version on version of squashfs-tools as you are asking in "i think this error becouse kernel version not equal squashfs-tools"

I am not sure how that affects your custom iso it should still boot just fine as ACL are not mandatory to boot or run Ubuntu and most people do not use them.

If you are having a problem with your custom iso you need to provide details of how you made it.

What was your base .iso ? What customization did you make ? and best, what command did you use to both make the squashfs and iso ?

Other than explain the cause of the message it is impossible to provide any further support due to the lack of information you have posted despite extended discussion.

Comment: so how i can disable ACL

Comment: See man page for setfacl , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339765/how-to-remove-acl-from-a-directory-and-back-to-usual-access-control , https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/remove-setfacl-840012/ or ask a new question. Comments are not for changing questions or extended discussion.

Comment: this is not solved my problem  get the same error

Comment: @MidoBona If you need help you need to explain your system and how you are using extended attributes. squashfs does not support them and so you posting here that it is not working if futile, we have already established that it will not work.

Comment: @MidoBona - You can consider filing a bug report against squashfs, but with what you posted I would expect it to be closed as either invalid or wont fix both by Ubuntu and upstream.