# i cant install right package squashfs for ubuntu 14.04

Tags: squashfs

I am using ubuntu server 14.04.1 and i want edit filesystem.squashfs after installed squashfs-tools and unsquashfs and edit filesystem and mksquashfs and build iso i get this error

```
base-installer: info: Using squashfs support for /cdrom/install/filesystem.squashfs
anna-install: Installing squashfs-modules
anna[21857]: DEBUG: resolver (kernel-image-4.2.0-16-generic-di): package doesn't exist (ignored)
anna[21857]: DEBUG: retrieving squashfs-modules-4.2.0-16-generic-di 4.2.0-16.19
kernel: [44.008353] squashfs: version 4.0 (2009/01/31) Phillip Lougher
main-menu[3537]: (process:21801): getfattr: .: Operation not supported
main-menu[3537]: (process:21801): getfattr: ./bin: Operation not supported
main-menu[3537]: (process:21801): getfattr: ./bin/bunzip2: Operation not supported
main-menu[3537]: (process:21801): getfattr: ./bin/bzcat: Operation not supported
main-menu[3537]: (process:21801): getfattr: ./bin/bzcmp: Operation not supported
```

i think this error becouse kernel version not equal squashfs-tools

is this right ?

and i want install right package squashfs-tools support kernel ubuntu-server 14.04.1

and sorry if my english is bad

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/962554/squashfs-operation-not-supported?noredirect=1#comment1539948_962554